# Inserting a new Page/tab using VBA in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm terrible with code and I've been searching around without success. I'm sure this has got to be something easy which is why I'm surprised I haven't found it. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology. In any case. I have setup a button that I want to be able to click and it automatically add a new Page/Tab (usually you right click and select "insert Page" which then adds a new page/tab in my form). I have the button set and all that's missing is the code. Does anyone know where a good resource is where I can find it? Or if you happen to have it pass it along? I'd greatly appreciate it!

-Deke

Comment: Lots of relevant answers come up in Google seacrh for "vba pages insert in tab control"

Comment: This will probably lead you in the right direction: [Expert Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27798635/Can't-programmatically-add-pages-in-tab-control.html)

Comment: the real problem is that you have to open the form in design mode. And once you added that tab, then what? You have to now start writing code to add controls. if this is a one time form create controls then fine, but any design that attempts to "self" modify or create controls at runtime is doomed to failure. You can't compile such applications, nor can you use the free runtime to distribute such applications. And the reason why you can't find examples is because no one attempts this kind of design that in practical terms never works well. Simple advice here is "dont' do it!"

Comment: So the idea I had was (and I was going to do this in stages as I figured each stage out) to click a button, have it insert a page, copy the format of another page (copy and paste basically) and then link to the next existing record in a table. What I'm getting is this is impossible? Just trying to make sure before I scrap this project.